Do someone proficient in kanji read furigana for kanji they know?
I know that one wouldn't need to, but I can imagine that once you read hiragana a lot you can't help it, just as someone proficient in roman letters can't help but read text when they look at it.
Also I have noticed that sometimes the furigana doesn't match up with the kanji, which I assume is for artistic effects (I see it somewhat often in song lyrics). If one skips furigana this would be missed, so wouldn't one have to read the furigana, just in case?

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question.  Your question seems to presuppose that the reader must read both the kanji and the furigana (ie., reading the same text twice).  But, that's not what happens (at least when I read a document).  If the furigana doesn't match the expected reading of the kanji, then you notice immediately; the difference stands out.  It's almost a bit like seeing the word "blue" written using red ink and the word "red" written in blue ink; your mind picks up on the discrepancy immediately.
In certain contexts, you might expect there to be artistic license taken, such as with lyrics where the kanji might suggest a deeper meaning than the words actually sung.  In certain genres of literature, you might also expect to see this.  But regardless, if you know how to read the kanji and you do so with ease, then you also will immediately notice when the furigana does not align with how you would otherwise have read the kanji.
